# Курьезный случай чередования прямой речи и слов автора

Tags: пунктуация

Как оформить прямую речь, расположенную после слов автора или предшествующую им, прерываемую или обрамленную ими, с кавычками и без кавычек, и даже без авторских ремарок — известно. Неописанными — или, быть может, мне не удалось найти это описание, — однако, остались случаи чередования прямой речи и слов автора. Надо полагать, это означает, что следует экстраполировать уже сформулированные правила на более сложные схемы. В целом экстраполяция удается неплохо, но бывают все же курьезные, на мой взгляд, явления.  Вот одно из них: «Фрейлейн не хотелось упускать ускользающую возможность проявить компетентность, поэтому, с целью придать значения своей фигуре, она провозгласила: "Хорошо", обрадованная тем, что может вернуться к родному языку, и в еще большей степени — тем, что благодаря своей сообразительности может вернуться за стойку и присесть ["][, —/:/?] [К/к]ак вас записать, сэр? ["]» Не поможете с экстраполяцией?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ОБРАЗЕЦ

Папа читал что-то и на вопрос мой: «Бывают ли синие зайцы?» – не поднимая головы, отвечал: «Бывают, мой друг, бывают».

КОММЕНТАРИЙ

Это обычное оформление прямой речи, тире (а не запятая) ставится после вопросительной прямой речи. Для сравнения: Пробормотав: «Барчуки проклятые», он закурил сигару и плотнее завернулся в шинель. Здесь встроенная повествовательная прямая речь, ставится запятая.

РЕШЕНИЕ

Фрейлейн не хотелось упускать ускользающую возможность проявить компетентность, поэтому, с целью придать значения своей фигуре, она провозгласила: "Хорошо", обрадованная тем, что может вернуться к родному языку, и в еще большей степени тем, что благодаря своей сообразительности может вернуться за стойку и присесть: "Как вас записать, сэр?

Comment: Благодарю Вас, облегчили мне страдания.

Answer (score 1):

А если поставить точку?

> ...может вернуться за стойку и присесть. "Как вас записать, сэр?"

Или, если дальше следует диалог, сразу его и начать, спустив эту реплику на следующую строку:

> ...может вернуться за стойку и присесть.
> — Как вас записать, сэр?

И не надо ли поставить тире перед словом "обрадованная"? Это ведь конец прямой речи и начало слов автора?

Comment: > И не надо ли поставить тире перед словом "обрадованная"? Это ведь конец прямой речи и начало слов автора?

В предложениях, состоящих из обрамленной словами автора прямой речи, после нее ставится либо тире, либо запятая, в зависимости от условий контекста. В данном случае оснований для постановки тире нет, прямая речь не служит таковым.

Comment: > А если поставить точку? Или, если дальше следует диалог, сразу его и начать, спустив эту реплику на следующую строку

Видите ли, художественная необходимость требует другого. Пунктуационное оформление, которое я пытаюсь привести с нормами морали и нравственности, создает впечатление, что героиня изрекла лишь "хорошо", пребывая в абсолютной уверенности в том, что тем самым придала себе веса, и это все, что она для этого сделала.

Comment: Когда же обнаруживается, что было что-то еще после запятой, становится ясно, что она пыталась произвести впечатление на этого сэра, продемонстрировав ему, что она, дескать, обременена высоким предназначением - ей нужно вписать его имя в регистрационную книгу. Таким образом достигается легкий комический эффект, который нивелируется, если поступить сообразно Вашим рекомендациям. Понимаете?

Comment: Тогда я за второй вариант из данных Людмилой -- с двоеточием.

Comment: > Тогда я за второй вариант из данных Людмилой -- с двоеточием.

Я тоже отдаю предпочтение этому варианту, но у меня двоеточие стоит и перед "Хорошо", причем в целесообразности его наличия я не сомневаюсь, оно абсолютно необходимо, от него все зависит.

Answer (score 1):

Возможны варианты:
1.С помощью диалога. Фрейлейн не хотелось упускать ускользающую возможность проявить компетентность, поэтому, с целью придать значения своей фигуре, она провозгласила:

-Хорошо.

Обрадованная тем, что может вернуться к родному языку и в еще большей степени тем, что благодаря своей сообразительности может вернуться за стойку и присесть, спросила:

—Как вас записать, сэр?

2.С помощью записи части прямой речи в виде дополнения-цитаты.

Фрейлейн не хотелось упускать ускользающую возможность проявить компетентность, поэтому, с целью придать значения своей фигуре, она провозгласила "Хорошо!", обрадованная тем, что может вернуться к родному языку, и в еще большей степени  тем, что благодаря своей сообразительности может вернуться за стойку и присесть : "Как вас записать, сэр? "

3.То же самое, но последняя фраза отдельной репликой диалога.